# Compound String Matching

Tags: regex

Suppose I have these strings (each line is a seperate string):

```
5207
002
LEC
WF 9:30AM - 10:20AM
RCH   302
Firas Mansour
01/04/2016 - 04/04/2016
```

I'm trying to create a regex that will match the `WF 9:30AM - 10:20AM` line. I'm having problems identifying what exactly it is that seperates that string from the others in terms of regex. The formatting of that line can vary a little bit:

- Call the WF part Part A. Part A can consist of 'M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', or any concatenated combination. In this example, part A is both W and F.
- Part B is the first time. This can be in 12h as in the example, or 24h like this: `M 19:00 - 20:50`
- After that is a hyphen and the second time in the same format as the first.

I'm not too sure how to attack this problem, any help would be great! If a regex matches only that line and none of the others, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should just put each part one after another:

```
^([MTWF]|Th)+ \d\d:\d\d([AP]M)? - \d\d:\d\d([AP]M)?$

 |----------| |---------------|   |---------------|
 ^                           ^      ^
 |                           |      part 3: same as part 2
 part 1: match one of these: |
 - "M", "T", "W", or "F"     |
 - "Th"                      |
                             part 2: match two digits, followed by a colon,
                                     followed by another two digits, then
                                     possible either "A" or "P" followed by
                                     "M"
```

The "^" at the beginning and the "$" at the end are to make sure the line doesn't have any other text.

If you care about only matching valid times (as opposed to any two digits for the hours), you can do something fancier, like this:

```
((1?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d|(1[0-2]|\d):[0-5]\d[AP]M)
```

Comment: this doesn't match the OPs example - i think you should replace `\d\d:\d\d([AP]M)?` with `\d{1,2}:\d\d([AP]M)?`

Comment: I would suggest to wrap the whole thing in `^...$`, and replace the spaces by the more forgiving `\s+` or `\s*` (the latter around the dash)

Comment: Wow thats perfect, worked for every example in my file. Thanks, and the explanation is great as well. I'm trying to learn regex... slowly but surely :D

Comment: @Nathan You'll get it eventually -- writing it at least -- don't try reading regex.

Comment: @Nathan That was sort of a joke, but regex is known for being very hard to read.

Comment: Good to know its not just me haha

Answer (score 3):

How about chaining the parts one after each other:

```
(?:[MTWF]|(?:Th))*\s\d+:\d\d(?:[AP]M)*\s-\s\d+:\d\d(?:[AP]M)*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

See a [demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RzseyKZwOLFoLIq2).

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @KSFT seems to be the same, and you were a little bit faster.

Comment: ty for the link, this site looks super helpful. +1